# How to measure the gain in memory usage when encoding strings in utf8 instead of utf16 in C#

Tags: c#

Supposedly, `ReadOnlySpan<byte> utf8 = "ab→cd"u8;` consumes twice as less memory when compared to `string utf16 = "ab→cd"`.

I'm struggling to find a way to "see it" with my own eyes since `Marshal.SizeOf()` does not work on those objects? (`Type 'System.String' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.`)

Comment: Strings in C# are UTF16, period. What you posted is a [UTF8 string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/utf8-string-literals) that's baked into the assembly code itself, viewed through a `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, a view to that byte array

Comment: Besides, `Sting` is a reference type and `Marshal.SizeOf` only works with structs and is used to calculate the size of the buffer array needed to pass them to unmanaged code. It's not a way to calculate the size of any object.

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion in the terms I used I'm new to programming!

Comment: This isn't about terms, it's a fundamental difference. What you created is a byte array. No string operations will work on it. UTF8 string literals aren't a way to save RAM. They're a way to avoid the encoding cost in high throughput web scenarios. Reducing the size of the `"AUTH "` constant to 5 bytes instead of 10 isn't useful. Reducing the penalty of encoding it to UTF8 5K times per second though, that's a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented in both ECMA-334 and ECMA-335 that strings are stored as UTF-16, which is double-bytes.

But you can prove it with the following simple example:

```cs
string a = "abc";
ReadOnlySpan<byte> b = "abc"u8;
Console.WriteLine(MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(a.AsSpan()).Length);
Console.WriteLine(b.Length);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3fnkl)

Note that `MemoryMarshal.AsBytes` does not do any conversion, it just reinterprets the `Span` to be in bytes.